# angular/ionic iframe issue on ios

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an issue with my ionic app on iphone. Ionic writes this into the index.html:

```
<iframe src="gap://ready" style="display:none;">...</iframe>
```

The console output of the app loops this error about 40 times per second:

```
Refused to load gap://ready because it appears in neither the child-src directive nor the default-src directive of the Content Security Policy.
```

I guess everytime the dirtycheck of angular is working, this error is thrown. Where is the iframe comming from and how can I get rid of the iframe and the error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution, simply add gap: to the following meta tag in `index.html`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: cdvfile: gap:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
```

Comment: This also fixed my problems with phonegap barcode scanner plugin not loading on iOS 10 !!!

Comment: Where to add this line.i am facing an issue barcode scanner is opening in iOS 10.

Comment: Add/extend this in the index.html header. I am using v1.2.4-nightly-1917, which already has a meta tag, but it's missing the 'gap:' content.

Comment: i've been working on this bug for a good part of a day. Thank you Marcel.